# Invention of Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion

Tags: discoveries

I know the principle of inclusion-exclusion and solved some problems related to this principle but I don't know how this principle was discovered?
Whenever I use this principle I was amazed thinking of how the concept of the principle of inclusion-exclusion came into the mathematicians head?
Can anyone tell me how mathematician discovered the principle of inclusion-exclusion in combinatorics? What problems led them to introduce the the principle of inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: Although this doesn't answer your question, I think the IEP is really quite natural. By drawing Venn diagrams, the case $n=2$ is obvious, the case $n=3$ is easy, and by then it's clear that there must be some generalization for all $n$ that can be found similarly. More relevant to your question is that in France the result is often called Poincaré's formula. I believe he proved it in his textbook on probability, though the result may have ben known earlier. I suspect it has been independently proven many times.

Comment: In his Enumerative Combinatorics, Richard Stanley quotes P. Stein  as saying the inclusion-exclusion principle “is doubtless very old; its origin is probably untraceable.”

Answer (score 2):

You can see [Inclusion–exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) :

> The name comes from the idea that the principle is based on over-generous inclusion, followed by compensating exclusion. This concept is attributed to Abraham de Moivre (1718); but it first appears in a paper of [Daniel da Silva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_da_Silva_(mathematician)) ("*Proprietades geraes et resolucao das Congruencias biniomis*", Lisbon 1854), and later in a paper by J.J. Sylvester (1883).

The source seems reliable; see :

- Leonard Eugene Dickson, [History of the Theory of Numbers, Volume I: Divisibility and Primality](https://books.google.it/books?id=FYWn8XWrAI0C&pg=PA119) (1919), page 119.

Comment: The principle also made its way to recreational mathematics in the late 19th century: ``say that 70 per cent lost an eye- 75 per cent an ear- 80 per cent an arm- 85 per cent a leg- that'll do beautifully. Now, my dear, what percentage, at least, must have lost all four?" (Lewis Carroll, The Tangled tale, Knot X, p. 69, London, Macmillan and co., 1885)